# Cannot start web-simulator on google actions for API.AI project

Tags: google-api, dialogflow-es

I am working on Google Cloud Platform to develop a project in API.AI, I have an integration (in API.AI) with Google Actions (for Google Home or Google Assistant), they provide me to see my progress as real time in web-simulator, that you can find here:

https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/web-simulator

I am trying to START the web-simulator clicking on START button, then I get a window pop-up but after open, it closes, I try and try again but I obtain the same result, I cannot open the web-simulator. I have allowed the popup windows in my browser.

Of course I have completed all steps to start web-simulator...

I don't know what is happening. Someone can help me? Thank you, have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, are you using a compatible browser? Try it in Chrome if you're
  not already using it, as Chrome is a Google product, and so is the
  web simulator.
- Next, are you using any Ad-Blockers or
  Script-Blockers like NoScript? If so, try disabling them, as they
  could interfere with the operation of the tool.
- If it still doesn't work, try going to an Incognito Windows by pressing the 
  three dots button and opening a New Incognito Window. Go to the page, and log
  in. This will ensure that no cookies are interfering.
- At this point, if you're still having issues, try a different browser. 
  (Either Firefox or Opera)

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Work on incognito session was perfect. I don't know what was happening, may be I need to allow cookies in normal session, but thank you.

Comment: Unless you've played with settings, cookies should work fine. Try logging out of your Google account on the non-Incognito window, then logging back in. If that doesn't work, try logging out, closing all Chrome windows, and logging back into your Google account.